# Laravel 5.3 - Is there bulid in way for form tampering protection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Is there any built in way to protect Forms from tampering, particularly adding or removing inputs to/from the form, from client side or editing the values of hidden fields ? I am coming from cakephp background and there is nice built-in security feature 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html#form-tampering-prevention

Please note, that I know the approach how it is being done in cake, and I understand that it can be manually implemented, the question is, is there any built-in way to go with.

Thanks

Comment: What's the scenario that you're worried about? If it's about data being added to the database, this is why the fillable fields array exists in the model. The validation rules also help narrow down the data that should be received, but with things like paying for products all the logic would be handled in the controller so the values could be pulled from the DB rather than the form post

Comment: I am aware of fillable/guarded attrs, and validation has its usage, but there are cases that hidden inputs makes things faster and easier

Comment: I agree, but without a scenario its difficult to give a more accurate answer

Comment: +1 for 'form tampering prevention' for Laravel. Example? I want to hide some FK's and PRIMARY key. I do not use simple forms - like one table/model for view -> I want to add Test/Quiz with Questions and Answers etc. -> I can't send everything in URL and validate ID's data. Part of them I can validate by doing complicated extra queries.. but why? One hidden field with crypted/decrypted form fields/values that User can not modify would be more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) can be used to make sure what fields are sent and what the content of these fields looks like.

There is also [csrf protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) that is enabled by default to make sure forms cannot be sent by another website.